# Optimize a vector function over global and local parameters

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have 2 functions F1(a, b, x) and F2(a, b, y).
I want to minimize the sum of F1 and F2 over a, b, x, y.

Naively I could define a new function F(a, b, x, y) = F1(a, b, x) + F2(a, b, y) and optimise this instead. However if I have an array of such functions:
[F1, F2, F3, F4 ...], Each having the same set of global parameters but one different local parameter, the number of optimization variables becomes very large!
Hence my question is, is there a better way to do it?

Not that it matters but, Fyi I'm using python atm.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: My question concerns more on implementation than the theory. I did come across mathematical articles that talk about the "what" but not the "how".